# Transaction receipts, blocks and confirmations

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, security, json-rpc, confirmations

In Bitcoin, there is a best practice to wait between three to six block confirmations before accepting an transaction. This is to avoid double spending. Are there similar rules of thumb in Ethereum?

Let's assume I am building a service that tracks Ethereum payment transactions. If I have an incoming tx hash, how can I check confirmations over Geth RPC API? I assume the transaction receipt should be used, but what numbers I should track to watch out for double spends and similar things. Is a transaction somehow invalidated if a double spend or other malign condition (fork?) is detected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the answers to the 3 questions on confirmations, checking for confirmations, and double spends.

---

1.
[What number of confirmations is considered secure in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum)

> 12 confirmations; however, exchanges and entities handling very large
>   amounts of Ether frequently are still encouraged to run two different
>   Ethereum implementations and only accept transactions that have been
>   confirmed by both for maximum security (e.g. Go & C++).

---

2.
Indeed, using the transaction receipt is a way to check confirmations.  Code example at: [How can a DApp detect a fork or chain reorganization using web3.js or additional libraries?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional)

---

3.
[Double spends are prevented](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/how-does-the-ethereum-eth-accounting-system-work-and-prevent-double-spends) because every account has a transaction count (nonce) that increases with each transaction.

Note: although each account has a nonce which prevents double spends, the nonce does **not** protect against [replay attacks.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-replay-attack)