# How does Ethereum know that I have enough ETH to spend?

Tags: verify

Ethereum uses account-based model. It means that if account A has 50 ETH and sends 10 ETH to account B, transaction will look like "send 10 ETH from A to B" (no inputs and outputs as in UTXO).

With this model, at some step Ethereum should check if account A really has 10 ETH to prevent double-spending.

My question is how, where (module/code/contract), and when Ethereum verifies that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for,

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1173/19016

> Each account has a globally accessible `nonce` which prevents double spends.  The `nonce` is the sequence number, which miners check, because a block that has a transaction with an incorrect nonce is an invalid block (other miners won't build on top of it).  (The `nonce` does **not** protect against [replay attacks.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-replay-attack))
>
> Second message (with higher nonce) can't be confirmed before the first.
>
> See [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/326/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ethereum-balances-vs-utxos) for complementary details such as:
>
> a global state stores a list of accounts with balances, code, and
> internal storage
>
> a transaction is valid if the sending account has enough balance to
> pay for it, in which case the sending account is debited and the
> receiving account is credited with the value

See https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/what-is-nonce aswell.

Comment: Account A has 50 ETH. It sends 30 ETH with nonce=1, and immediately after again 30 ETH with nonce=2. Miners then sort these transactions by nonce, and apply them one-by-one (at the same time they do check "if banalce(A) >= X ETH"), right?