# Importing presale wallet into Geth without downloading all the blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, light-clients

Importing presale wallet into Geth without downloading all the blockchain

I was wondering if it is possible to import a presale wallet into Geth without downloading the whole blockchain. I mean, is it possible to import the wallet immediately after starting Geth without syncing the whole blockchain

I am using Linux Ubuntu 15.10 and my harddrive space is a bit limited.

If the above if possible I am also wondering if it is possible to transfer the funds without syncing the whole blockchain.

Answer (score 3):

You can import pre-sale wallets without syncing the blockchain. I did that recently on a offline debian machine. You will end up with a regular "account" file in "./ethereum/keystore" which you can move to any synced geth instance and transact.

For the transfer part of your question, have a look at this: [Is there any safe way to send money from a cold wallet, using an untrusted computer?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/is-there-any-safe-way-to-send-money-from-a-cold-wallet-using-an-untrusted-compu)

Answer (score 2):

As @m0se said the import is independent from having a blockchain. Why is that and how does it work?

```
geth wallet import /path/to/my/presale.wallet
```

This command will ask you for your wallet password and decrypt your wallet into the keystore ~/.ethereum/keystore/
But then you need a fully synced node to send the transaction.

Comfortable alternatives are [myethwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com) or [kraken's presale wallet importer](https://kraken.com/eth)
Both handle the decryption of your wallet offline, sign the transaction offline and then send the transaction to their own *geth* node. You are not required to have a *geth* running on your computer.