# How can I sign a transaction using c#?

Tags: json-rpc, c#, nethereum

I want to create a signed transaction using C#, which will later be used by Nethereum via JSON-RPC to call eth_sendRawTransaction.

I have the raw transaction and the private key, now how do I sign the data with the key?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I asked something similar here: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions

Comment: @OriMarron How did you run ethereumjs-tx in the .NET environment?

Comment: It's quite dirty, I loaded phantomJS using Selenium, which allowed me to simulate a browser to call the JS code. 
A less dirty solution could be to use a nodeJS server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand the other response, to provide offline transaction signing in Nethereum you can do the following:

First, you will need your private key, and sender address. You can retrieve the sender address from your private key using `Nethereum.Core.Signing.Crypto.EthECKey.GetPublicAddress(privateKey);` if you only have the private key.

`var privateKey = "0xb5b1870957d373ef0eeffecc6e4812c0fd08f554b37b233526acc331bf1544f7";
var senderAddress = "0x12890d2cce102216644c59daE5baed380d84830c";`

Now using web3 first you will need to retrieve the total number of transactions of your sender address.

`var web3 = new Web3();
 var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(senderAddress);`

The txCount will be used as the nonce to sign the transaction.

Now using web3 again, you can build an encoded transaction as following:

`var encoded = web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.SignTransaction(privateKey, receiveAddress, 10, txCount.Value);`

If you need to include the data and gas there are overloads for it.

You can verify an encoded transaction:
                    `Assert.True(web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.VerifyTransaction(encoded));`

Or get the sender address from an encoded transaction:

`web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.GetSenderAddress(encoded);`

To send the encoded transaction you will "SendRawTransaction"

`var txId = await web3.Eth.Transactions.SendRawTransaction.SendRequestAsync("0x" + encoded);`

You can see this example on the [unit test](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.Web3.Tests/TransactionSigningTests.cs)

Or a "real" implementation [on the Game sample](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum.Game.Sample/blob/master/Forms/Core/Ethereum/GameScoreService.cs)

Comment: hey Juan, your unit test link got outdated :) you should use a git-tag-based link ;)

Comment: do you have example with curl + json rpc. If yes please share

Answer (score 6):

Nethereum now supports offline transaction signing, so there is no longer a need to use EdgeJs or similar to run node scripts inside the .NET environment.