# ethereum offline signer c#

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nethereum, c#

is there any C# version of the offline signer for transaction. like ethereumjs-tx

var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
var privateKey = new Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx)
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize()
console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'))

need similar in c# i am trying nethereum this implementation not working

[How can I sign a transaction using c#?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3823/how-can-i-sign-a-transaction-using-c)

var privateKey = "0xb5b1870957d373ef0eeffecc6e4812c0fd08f554b37b233526acc331bf1544f7";
var senderAddress = "0x12890d2cce102216644c59daE5baed380d84830c";

Now using web3 first you will need to retrieve the total number of transactions of your sender address.

var web3 = new Web3();
 var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(senderAddress);

The txCount will be used as the nonce to sign the transaction.

Now using web3 again, you can build an encoded transaction as following:

var encoded = web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.SignTransaction(privateKey, receiveAddress, 10, txCount.Value);

If you need to include the data and gas there are overloads for it.

You can verify an encoded transaction: Assert.True(web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.VerifyTransaction(encoded));

Or get the sender address from an encoded transaction:

web3.OfflineTransactionSigning.GetSenderAddress(encoded);

To send the encoded transaction you will "SendRawTransaction"

var txId = await web3.Eth.Transactions.SendRawTransaction.SendRequestAsync("0x" + encoded);

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question.

https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/web3/

You have offline transaction signing function but the docs have not been updated. 
The method call looks different now because it was moved to static context or something like that:

Web3.OfflineTransactionSigner.SignTransaction.....

For more info check this out: https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/issues/151

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a signer based on secp256k1lib instead of Bouncy Castle then you probably would like to use the signer from Nethermind project:

Proxy for secp256k1lib:
https://github.com/tkstanczak/nethermind/tree/master/src/Nethermind/Nethermind.Secp256k1

Actual usage with Ethereum protocol specifics that you may want to look at to base your solution on:
https://github.com/tkstanczak/nethermind/blob/master/src/Nethermind/Nethermind.Core/Crypto/EthereumSigner.cs