# How to execute Owner only methods in a contract from Web3 JS

Tags: web3js, nodejs

Assuming there is a contract deployed at `0x332a5fbdfd0b3ba6dd1d35e4e3c86562024f737d` whose **Owner** is `0x0136d0ccac4464f920eeab664e847f4e69bd5fcf`. The contract has a `ownerOnly` method named `incrementNumber()`, how should we go about executing this method from a standalone Node.js server?

I'm using testrpc in mac for testing this - I have access to the private keys (not sure what the password of the accounts are in Testrpc)

Answer (score 2):

With web3 v1 installed, you can try this:

```
let abi = fs.readFileSync("YourContract.abi").toString();
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
let transaction = contract.methods.yourMethod(yourArguments);

let options = {
    to  : transaction._parent._address,
    data: transaction.encodeABI(),
    gas : await transaction.estimateGas({from: OWNER_PUBLIC_KEY}),
};

let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY);
let transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
```

Please note that for the last line, waiting for the transaction-receipt is not necessarily the best course of action. You might prefer to get the transaction-hash and then use it in order to wait for the transaction-receipt elsewhere in your server. See [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html#callbacks-promises-events) for a more detailed description of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the owner is one of the accounts generated by testrpc, let's say `accounts[0]`. These accounts are accessible from your web3 provider in your node.js script. 
For example you could have:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
if (typeof web3 != 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
}
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;
var owner = accounts[0];
[...] // fetch contract instance at given address
contract.method(arg1, arg2, {from: owner, gas: 999999});
```

where of course `localhost:8545` should be the hostname and port your testrpc instance is listening to.

Comment: But doesn't that need private key / transaction signing? The setup will be deployed in a remote server and connecting to mainnet

Comment: you mentioned testrpc in your question, so that's what I assumed you were using; in that case no signing is required, as accounts come already unlocked. If you are using a regular ethereum client to connect to the mainnet, of course you need to have the private key to sign transactions; everything would work exactly in the same way except that you would need to (assuming you use geth) `geth attach` to it and `personal.unlockAccount()` with the password, or similarly for other clients.

Comment: how do we go about for signing a transaction?

Comment: it's done automatically by web3, provided you unlocked your account in your ethereum client. Alternatively you can use other libraries to sign a transaction manually, see this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/using-web3-to-sign-a-transaction-without-connecting-to-geth