# RPC transfer funds doesn't work

Tags: transactions, json-rpc

I want to transfer some ether from one account to another. I use curl command in ubuntu, there is my request:

> curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from": "0x1AC78935Ac45149C2655c9e475F16923E31a7FEd", "to": "0x777D32127644ca2a37BD0384CF0d881BB3aCbB31", "value": "0x288232983"}],"id":1}' https://ropsten.infura.io/YOUR_TOKEN

But after than returns nothing and transaction doesn't work. Also i tried with `eth_call` instead of `eth_sendTransaction`, the same problem. If anyone has this problem,please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [eth_sendTransaction](https://infura.io/docs/#supported-json-rpc-methods) is not among the supported methods by Infura.io. You have to create the transaction using for example [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx), and send it using eth_sendRawTransaction which is supported.

Comment: Now I get error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32602,"message":"invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Bytes"}}

Comment: What was your json request?

Comment: curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendRawTransaction","params":[{"from": "0x1AC78935Ac45149C2655c9e475F16923E31a7FEd", "to": "0x777D32127644ca2a37BD0384CF0d881BB3aCbB31", "value": "0x288232983"}, "mypass"],"id":1}' https://ropsten.infura.io/token

Comment: sendRawTransaction has a different syntax.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction. You have to create the signed transaction like this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3392, and use the result as parameter.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw. It is a wrapper to sendRawTransaction and encapsulates many complexities.