# Is it possible to serialize transaction data on geth or PHP?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

I need ethereumjs-tx in PHP. Seems there is no PHP library so far. I found only JS and Python Library. Is it possible to serialize transaction data on geth? If not, I will use nodejs or create the PHP library. Before that, I want to ask this question.

What I need:

```
$rawTx = [
  'nonce' => '0x17',
  'gasPrice' => '0x4a817c800',
  'gasLimit' => '0x5209',
  'to' => '0x5dbb9793537515398a1176d365b636a5321d9e39',
  'value' => '0xde0b6b3a7640000',
  'data' => '',
  'chainId' => 3
];

$tx = new Tx($rawTx);
$serializedTx = $tx->serialize(); // or access geth function if it possible
```

ethereumjs-tx

[Create and sign OFFLINE raw transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions/3392#3392)

Comment: any luck for your problem? If yes please share I am also looking same solution

Comment: Data serialization should be easy with [ethereum-php](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php). I would love to add this feature but it's not in hight priority yet. Ping me if you want to help to implement "serialize()" and by adding tests.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a solution, there is this implementation available:

https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-tx