# How could I write "sendrawtransaction" in Python?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

Since I am using `web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/root@123'))`

That's why I have to use sendrawtransaction for ether transaction . Now what is the process of write `sendrawtransaction` in PYTHON ?

And if there is any other process of transaction using this `Httpprovider` in pythhon then please mention .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're just trying to figure out how to send a transaction using [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py). If so, something like this should work:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    'from': '0x...',
    'to': '0x...',
    'value': web3.toWei(1, 'ether'),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sign a transaction with pyethereum. See the pyethereum answer here:
[Create and sign OFFLINE raw transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions)

Answer (score 1):

You may refer the official doc [here](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.sendRawTransaction). 
It gives an example as follow,

> ```
> >>> import rlp
> >>> from ethereum.transactions import Transaction
> >>> tx = Transaction(
>     nonce=web3.eth.getTransactionCount(web3.eth.coinbase),
>     gasprice=web3.eth.gasPrice,
>     startgas=100000,
>     to='0xd3cda913deb6f67967b99d67acdfa1712c293601',
>     value=12345,
>     data=b'',
> )
> >>> tx.sign(the_private_key_for_the_from_account)
> >>> raw_tx = rlp.encode(tx)
> >>> raw_tx_hex = web3.toHex(raw_tx)
> >>> web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(raw_tx_hex)
> '0xe670ec64341771606e55d6b4ca35a1a6b75ee3d5145a99d05921026d1527331'
> ```