# Signing Multisig Wallet Contract transactions Offline in geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, multisignature, offline

I have setup a multisig contract using the standard [Wallet Contract](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/74414d36c2453a468116d5884e28eaa6eb1723e5/Wallet.sol) and have been interacting with it on my geth console successfully as per the [Mist Wallet Contract wiki entry](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/wiki/Wallet-Contract).

So far I've been able to successfully call "execute" and "confirm" on the contract via the console. However, I now want to do this completely offline.

My code currently does the following:

```
var myAddress = "0xContractAddress";
var myContract = eth.contract("contractABI_here");
var myInstance = myContract.at(myAddress);
toAddress = "0xDestinationAccount";
amtGas = 100000;
requestAddress = "0xSigner1Address";
requestAddressNonce = someNonce; // Get the correct nonce
valueWithdrawn = web3.toWei(someValue, "ether");
personal.unlockAccount(requestAddress)
myInstance.execute(toAddress, valueWithdrawn, "", { from: requestAddress, gas: amtGas, nonce: requestAddressNonce } );
```

However, that last instruction returns in an off-line, unsynced node:

> Error: exceeds block gas limit

If I set amtGas to less than 5001 then it returns in the offline node:

> Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

I saw people had a similar problem when signing regular transactions and [this stackexchange post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions/28648#28648) suggests to use signTransaction but I can't figure out how to sign the transaction generated by myInstance.execute(....)

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I believe I have found the answer.

You can call getData and then use that as an input to sign the transaction:

```
data = myInstance.execute.getData(toAddress, valueWithdrawn, "" );
eth.signTransaction({ from: requestAddress, gas: amtGas, nonce: requestAddressNonce, data: data })
```

You can then grab the "raw" output, copy it to an online machine, and call sendRawTransaction on it.