# How do I create a raw signed transaction and write it in hex?

Tags: etherscan

I am looking to send a tx through etherscan's pushTx function as seen here : https://etherscan.io/pushTx

Is there a sort of template I can use to define addresses, token contract or ETH, gas price etc. and then encode it to hex to send through this pushTx?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28648/55116

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh: In this answer, the call to `accounts.signTransaction` does not include the `data` field, which means it allows only for the transaction of ether-transfer (i.e., no function calls). So this answer is very partial.

Comment: I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Basically what you are trying to do is an "offline transaction".
For example "MyEtherWallet" has a non coding way in realizing that.
Alternativly walletsoftware has functionality for this too.

In addition there are alternative services like Infura or even cloudflare who offer an api for posting transactions into the blockchain.

Comment: @goodvibration good point!  I guess combine the answer with another on ABI encoding...