# How to prepare a transaction from the server and sign it in the front-end?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, frontend, server-side

Is there a way to prepare a transaction from the server, then wait for the user to sign the transaction from the frontend with Metamask, before running other functions from the server (e.g., update a database)?

Or do I have to call all endpoints from the front end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create and sign OFFLINE raw transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3386/create-and-sign-offline-raw-transactions)

Comment: Not really. I want users to sign their transactions with Metamask so I don't have to manage private keys via the backend

Comment: Oh, I see. Then [EIP-712](https://medium.com/metamask/eip712-is-coming-what-to-expect-and-how-to-use-it-bb92fd1a7a26) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @rkhan The correct way to do that is for the backend to listen contract events that will be triggered when the user submit the transaction, because you won't be sure the user submitted the correct transaction until it is mined.