# How to sign offline with geth?

Tags: cold-storage, offline

I have installed geth on an offline-computer and created a account with `./geth account new`. Than I have copied (USB-Stick) the resulting file from the offline-computers `keystore/` to an online-computer, where I can check the balance of that account. Of course I will never type the passphrase for that account on the online-computer.

How can I transfer Ethers from the account using only geth? (I do not want to install any third-party software on the offline-computer.)

I have read [other posts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/is-there-any-safe-way-to-send-money-from-a-cold-wallet-using-an-untrusted-compu) saying "using the unofficial RPC method eth.signTransaction". Unfortunately it's not clear to me, if this is related to geth or an other tool. I would very much appreciate to sign offline just with geth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's clear some things:

- the file created by `geth account new` is the file you don't want to end up on a computer connected to a network. It's the file that you want to have hidden somewhere, where nobody else knows where it is
- you can check the balance for any account either locally in a synced geth client or on https://etherscan.io, without ever uploading that file anywhere. With geth it's done by running in the console `web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0x....'), 'ether')` where you replace `0x....` with your actual account

In order to send money out of that new account using `geth`, without storing the wallet on an internet connected computer is documented [here on stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28648/12836).