# MEW - Is it possible to generate transactions for "Contracts" offline?

Tags: transactions, offline

I am trying to use MEW on an offline computer under the tab "Contracts". Is this possible ? When I try it, I get to the final step where the pop up box lets me hit the "Generate Transaction" button, but then nothing happens. Any ideas ? If I am on an online computer, the transaction generates fine. But I don't want to expose my private key online. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You technically can. I've summarized the steps from MyEtherWallet below:

1. From the online computer, go to the offline transaction page and fill in the address you're sending from.
2. Go to the offline computer, and on the offline transaction page, fill in the to address and your amount. From step 1, you should have a nonce and a gas price.
3. Sign the transaction on the offline computer. You can generate a transaction on the offline transaction page.
4. Copy the signed transaction to the online computer. On the offline transaction page on the online computer again, add the signed information and hit send.

This is heavily based on the instructions from [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/offline/making-offline-transaction-on-myetherwallet.html) related to sending transactions offline. There's also a page on [how this is possible](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/offline/sending-offline-with-myetherwallet.html).

Comment: MyEtherWallet has an explicit option "Send Offline" that provide multi step guide how to sign a transfer offline and broadcast online. It should be possible to create a contract from such interface but it doesn't appear to be easy.

Comment: @Ismael you should post [the guide](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets/guides/how-to-use-myetherwallet/) as an answer and I'll upvote you, then.

Comment: @Ismael you didn't post the guide as an answer, so I've edited my original answer and added it. I also flagged it as a dupe since https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/is-there-any-safe-way-to-send-money-from-a-cold-wallet-using-an-untrusted-compu answers it.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I know how to use the "Send Offline" option in MEW. But that option is NOT for a contract. I am trying to generate a transaction for a "Contract", for example to register EOS tokens. @Ismael, if you post a guide, I'll also upvote you. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: @K2A1 I've tried against ropsten but latest version of MEW doesn't seems to work with a mnemonic phrase. To deploy a contract "To Address" should be null (or 0x0 can't check which one works) and "Data" should contain your contract bytecode.

Comment: @Ismael, thank you for the answer. Looks like MEW would need to add functionality for offline contract generation in the future.